# Using a Matrix to Populate Every Other Value in a Column

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

Im learning matlab as I have free time.
Matrix B is half the length of Matrix C
I want Every Value in the first column of matrix B to populate every other Value in the first column of Matrix C
To do this Im using a for loop. Currently I get every other value populated with the last number in the column of matrix B. What do I need to change?

```
Z=length(A);
X = length(B);
C = zeros(size(A);
for n = 1:2:Z
    for m = 1:1:X               
         C(n,1) = B(m,1);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) function:

```
reps = 2;
delta = zeros(reps,1);
B = magic(5);
C = kron(B,delta);
```

Here `rep` indicates that every second value should be taken from `B`. But you can also duplicate the values by using `delta = ones(reps,1);`, or any mix that you are interested in, by modifying `delta`.

Additionally you can change the dimension of `delta` to a row vector and then can duplicate values along the rows. Or by allowing `delta` to be a matrix you can be get more fancy stuff.

Comment: I got this to work with what I wanted and saved me a step down the line by using it to populate a 2nd column. I ended up using a for loop to populate every other value with a zero to achieve what I wanted. Thank You for showing me this!

Comment: Yeah doing this you do not need to use any for-loops, even if you do not want these value to be zero you can change them afterwards `C(C==0) = NewValue;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this:

```
B = magic(4); % The small matrix with the values
C = zeros(size(A)*2); % The matrix to fill the values in
C(1:2:end,1) = B(:,1) % populating the matrix
```

and you get:

```
C =
    16     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```